# Call FancyBox with ID instead of class

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a link with a class applied to it that makes it look like a button IE gives it some basic styling, padding and a background color etc

```
<a href="mypage.html" class="blue-button">Click me</a>
```

I've now decided to use FancyApps / fancybox (v2.1) to trigger a popup window in an iframe instead.

My issue is the actual code FancyBox tells me to use **ALSO** has a class so I endup with 2 classes applied to my link and breaking my button and Fancybox popup.
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

```
<a href="mypage.html" class="callback" class="blue-button" data-fancybox-type="iframe" >Request Call back</a>
```

Here's my fancybox script...

```
$(".callback").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 510,
        maxHeight   : 510,
        fitToView   : true,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        'overlayColor'  : '#1C5093',
        'overlayOpacity': 0.9


    });
```

Can anyone help me out. If possible, I'd like to retain my own class of "blue-button" and then call Fancybox with an id instead.

BTW, I am learning jQuery (slowly) and have the visual QuickStart guide but i'm obviously just starting out. really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set two classes to your `<a>` element with an incorrect format

```
<a href="mypage.html" class="callback" class="blue-button" data-fancybox-type="iframe" >Request Call back</a>
```

Set the two classes within the same `class` attribute (separate each new class name by space(s)) like :

```
<a href="mypage.html" class="callback blue-button" data-fancybox-type="iframe" >Request Call back</a>
```